# What did Peano meant by "R. Universitate"?

Tags: publications, university

In a book written by Giuseppe **Peano**, it is written "Prof in R. Universitate de Torino" i.e. "Prof in R. University of Turin".

I guess "R" stands for "royal" but I have no proof of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[EDIT: corrected adding "regia" after @MassimoOrtolano's comment].

Yes, it surely stands for *regia* or *reale* (both words mean "of the king" in Italian); that adjective was common in pre-war Italy and there are other "royal" universities around. The standard Italian form is "regia (reale) università di Torino"; Peano wrote in an [unusual language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latino_sine_flexione).

Would [this](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZucG5RxI5P0C&lpg=PT373&ots=gXI4eDogj4&dq=%22reale%20universit%C3%A0%20di%20torino%22&hl=it&pg=PT373#v=onepage&q=%22reale%20universit%C3%A0%20di%20torino%22&f=false) and [this](http://www.museotorino.it/resources/pdf/books/490/files/assets/common/downloads/publication.pdf) document be proof enough for you that it was the full name?